# Accessing the internal buffer of a BinaryReader

Tags: c#, binary, endianness, binaryreader

I'm inheriting the `BinaryReader` class.

I have to override some essential methods like [`ReadUInt16`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/binaryreader.cs).

The internal implementation of this method is:

```
public virtual ushort ReadUInt16(){
   FillBuffer(2);
   return (ushort)(m_buffer[0] | m_buffer[1] << 8);
}
```

The binary files I'm reading from are organized as high byte first (big endian), and I've inherited from the `BinaryReader` also because I had to add some more functionality.
Anyway I want to implement the swapping in the subclass itself.

Is there another way to access `m_buffer` or alternative without using reflection or other consuming resources?
May be I should override the `FillBuffer` and back up peeked bytes? Or maybe just ignoring it? Will it have side effects? Has anyone faced this before? Can anyone explain why is `FillBuffer` not internal? Is it required to always fill the buffer or it can be skipped? And now that it's not internal why wasn't a protected getter to the `m_buffer` field implemented along?

Here's the implementation of `FillBuffer`.

```
protected virtual void FillBuffer(int numBytes) {
    if (m_buffer != null && (numBytes < 0 || numBytes > m_buffer.Length)) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("numBytes", 
            Environment
            .GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_BinaryReaderFillBuffer"));
    }
    int bytesRead=0;
    int n = 0;

    if (m_stream==null) __Error.FileNotOpen();

    // Need to find a good threshold for calling ReadByte() repeatedly
    // vs. calling Read(byte[], int, int) for both buffered & unbuffered
    // streams.
    if (numBytes==1) {
        n = m_stream.ReadByte();
        if (n==-1)
            __Error.EndOfFile();
        m_buffer[0] = (byte)n;
        return;
    }

    do {
        n = m_stream.Read(m_buffer, bytesRead, numBytes-bytesRead);
        if (n==0) {
            __Error.EndOfFile();
        }
        bytesRead+=n;
    } while (bytesRead<numBytes);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a good idea to try accessing the internal buffer. Why not do something like:

```
var val = base.ReadUInt16();
return (ushort)((val << 8) | ((val >> 8) & 0xFF));
```

Slightly slower than reading from the buffer directly, but I seriously doubt that this is going to make a material impact on the overall speed of your application.

`FillBuffer` is apparently an implementation detail that for some reason the Framework team decided they needed to make `protected`, possibly because some other Framework class takes advantage of the internal workings of `BinaryReader`. Since you know that all it does is fill the internal buffer, and your derived class doesn't have access to the internal buffer, so if you do decide to rewrite the reading implementation yourself, I'd suggest that you ignore that method. Calling it can't do you any good, and could do you great harm.

You might be interested in a [series of articles](https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=693) I wrote some years ago, in which I implemented a `BinaryReaderWriter` class, which is essentially a `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter` joined together, and allows you random read/write access to the underlying stream.

Comment: You said it's required to call the method before trying to access the buffer, but what if the buffer isn't accessible at all?? They should've make this method internal or provide a getter wrapper to the buffer. I prefer performance since I'm dealing with large binary files, I'm just gonna ignore the FillBuffer. Please refer to it more specifically in you answer it should be clearer for other users.  Do you believe saving the swap is redundant optimization (I need to override all the numeric readers).

Comment: Yes, I do believe that saving the swap is redundant optimization. Compared to the amount of time it takes to read data from a disk file, a few million swaps is nothing. As for the `FillBuffer` method, I'd not worry about it. It's apparently an implementation detail that for some unknown reason the Framework team thought they needed to expose. Possibly because a different .NET class uses it. And as you say, since its function is to fill an internal buffer that your derived class has no access to, it wouldn't do you any good to call it.

Comment: Jim, what's the point including `& 0xFF` to the bits just shifted right? Isn't it the same result as without using it? Can you please refer me to an article that explains that?
And BTW, I just subscribed to your blog, I love it!

Comment: @Shimmy: The `&0xFF` probably isn't needed. I suspect I was thinking of shifting `int` when I wrote that.